# What is the advantages of using cimport in python?

Tags: python, indexing, cython

I recently started working with cython and found it amazingly fast. I've seen many codes that `cimport` modules (like `cimport numpy`), but I don't know what are `cimport` special features that `import` lacks.
 why some programmers use both `import` and `cimport` for a specific module (like numpy).
 I also want to know if anyone can explain that what is **efficient indexing** and how can I make use of it by cimporting numpy module?
Thanks

Comment: What does [the documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html) tell you? Is there anything you want to ask specifically referencing that documentation that you don't understand? Do you know how dynamic linking works for compiled DLL / .so files at all, and why C uses `.h` header files to include in other projects?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I haven’t seen your comment… You’re right.

Comment: @MartinPieters My main problem is that I only write codes and I know little about the background interactions. maybe I should study the references before I ask questions. And I have to say that I haven't heard of things you just asked me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**cimport** = “Cython import”

According to the [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html):

> A Cython module can be split into two parts: a definition file with a `.pxd` suffix, containing C declarations that are to be available to other Cython modules, and an implementation file with a `.pyx` suffix, containing everything else. When a module wants to use something declared in another module’s definition file, it imports it using the **cimport** statement.